# React Bootstrap reset form after submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, react-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to setup a contact form with React Bootstrap in a React/Next.js app. How would I reset the form after submitting it? When I added a reset handle the validation did not work anymore.

```
  // Form validation
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

  // Thank you Message
  const [thankYouMessage, setThankYouMessage] = useState(false);

  // Form submit handler
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    const formData = new FormData();

    Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
      if (!field.name) return;
      formData.append(field.name, field.value);
    });

    await fetch(
      "https://domain.tld/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1234/feedback",
      {
        body: formData,
        method: "POST",
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
          setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
        } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
          alert("Message failed to send.");
        }
      });

    setValidated(true);
  }
```

This is the form:

```
  <div>
    <Form
      noValidate
      validated={validated}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <Form.Group controlId="your-name">
        <Form.Control
          required
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your name"
          name="your-name"
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
          Please enter your name
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="your-email">
        <Form.Control
          required
          type="email"
          placeholder="Your email address"
          name="your-email"
        />
        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
          Please enter your email
        </Form.Control.Feedback>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="your-message">
        <Form.Control
          as="textarea"
          cols={30}
          rows={6}
          placeholder="Write your message..."
          name="your-message"
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button type="submit" variant="primary" size="lg">
        Send Message
        <span></span>
      </Button>
    </Form>
    <Alert
      variant="success"
      className={thankYouMessage ? "d-block mt-3" : "d-none"}
    >
      Thank you for your message. It has been sent.
    </Alert>
  </div>
```

I have tried setting up a reset handle with `useRef()` but it did not work:

```
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const handleReset = () => {
    formRef.current.reset();
    setValidated(false);
  };
```

Then on the form added `ref={formRef}` and right after `setValidated(true);` I did `handleReset();` but then the validation does not work anymore.
Any suggestions about this are welcome and any comments on the code as well!

Here's an gif of what happens when adding `ref={formRef}` to the Form tag and:

```
  const formRef = useRef();
  const handleReset = () => {
    formRef.current.reset();
    setValidated(false);
  };
```

and in the fetch:

```
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
          setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
          handleReset();
        } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
          alert("Message failed to send.");
        }
      });
```

[image: Form validation]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to get response first before resetting? `e.preventDefault()` is preventing the form from resetting, but by removing that, the page just reloads immediately without waiting for the response. If that is the issue that you're facing, then there are a few solutions:

1. Use [reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) (just reloads the current document).

```
    .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
              setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
            } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
              alert("Message failed to send.");
            }
            location.reload();
          });
```

2. Use [submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) (just submits form without sending submit event or form validation but this is fine because you have already validated it previously).

```
    const formRef = useRef(null);

    ...

    .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
              setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
            } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
              alert("Message failed to send.");
            }
            formRef.current.submit();
          });

    ...

    <Form
      noValidate
      validated={validated}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      ref={formRef}
    >
```

3. Use [requestSubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) (same as clicking the submit button). `EventListener` is needed here because essentially, what you want is to disable default action by calling `preventDefault` first, then enable default action again after getting response. Unfortunately, there is no such convenient `enableDefault` function.

   The flow is like this:

   1. `addEventListener` with `preventDefault` is called (now any button clicks **will not** reset the form)
   2. Fill the form and click submit button
   3. Fetch and received response
   4. `removeEventListener` with `preventDefault` is called (now any button clicks **will** reset the form)
   5. call `requestSubmit` to submit the form as if the submit button is clicked, which will reset the form

```
    const formRef = useRef(null);

    ...

    // useCallback is needed here instead of a normal function because
    // formRef will be updated every time onChange occurs because react renders again
    // which will cause addEventListener/removeEventListener to not work as expected 
    const stopReset = useCallback((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // stopPropagation will prevent form validation but if you really need it here
        // then you need to add another event listener for handleSubmit in useEffect
        // and you can remove onSubmit={handleSubmit} in Form
        // event.stopPropagation();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        formRef.current.addEventListener('submit', stopReset);
        // Uncomment this only if you need stopPropagation above
        // formRef.current.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
    },[]); // Add dependencies in the array, leave it blank if you don't have any

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        // remove preventDefault and stopPropagation here
    
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        Array.from(e.currentTarget.elements).forEach((field) => {
          if (!field.name) return;
          formData.append(field.name, field.value);
        });
    
        await fetch(
          "https://domain.tld/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1234/feedback",
          {
            body: formData,
            method: "POST",
          }
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
              setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
            } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
              alert("Message failed to send.");
            }
            formRef.current.removeEventListener('submit', stopReset);
            formRef.current.requestSubmit()
          });
    
        setValidated(true);
    }

    ...

    <Form
      noValidate
      validated={validated}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      ref={formRef}
    >
```

If you want to display your message for awhile before resetting, you can add a timer.

```
    .then(async (response) => {
            if (response.status === "mail_sent") {
              setThankYouMessage(!thankYouMessage);
            } else if (response.status === "mail_failed") {
              alert("Message failed to send.");
            }
            // sleep for 10 seconds
            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000));
            // call whichever method to reset
          });
```

Comment: I've tried your first 2 solution and does not work, because then the validation does not work anymore. With that it it sends the form anyway without validating. When I add `const formRef = useRef();` it still validates but validation does not get cleared when submitting the form.

Comment: @Mark Can you try the first 2 with a timer? If you want to clear validation then you need to call `setValidated(false);` as well.

Comment: Sure. Also check out my post, just have added some more explanation and an GIF to show what's happening when adding `const formRef = useRef();`

Comment: When I add `setValidated(false);` to the fetch `if (response.status === "mail_sent")` it still does not remove the validation as showed in the GIF in my post. It does clear the form though.

Comment: Can you try resetting the `className`? `formRef.current.className = ""` or `formRef.current.classList.remove("was-validated")`

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the custom validation of React Bootstrap because when I remove `noValidate` from the `<Form>` component it works with validation and resetting after submit.